# Restricting Entity Access via Multi-Entity Relationship Conditions

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have multiple entities in Symfony 6 that I want to connect within the security context of API-Platform. Below, I've posted excerpts of the relevant entities.

I'm trying to restrict the "Messages" entity. A user who wants to retrieve the messages can only do so for messages in which they are listed in the notification along with the corresponding message. If this is the case, they are allowed to read the message.

How can I implement my plan? Have i to create a Voter or is it possible to solve this with API-Platform attributes?

Here is my attempt in invalid code, to better explain my purposes:

```
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get('notification.user == user and notification.message == this.message')
)]
```

User.php:

```
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(security: 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN") or object == user'),
        new GetCollection(security: 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN")'),
        new Post(security: 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN")'),
        new Put(security: 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN") or object == user'),
        new Patch(security: 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN") or object == user'),

        new Delete(security: 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN") or object == user')
    ],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['user:read']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['user:write']],
)]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[Groups(['user:read'])]
    private int $id;
```

Message.php:

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MessageRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(),
        new GetCollection(),
        new Post(),
        new Put(),
        new Patch(),
        new Delete()
    ],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['message:read']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['message:write']]
)]
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['subproject' => 'exact'])]
class Message
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['message:read'])]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['message:read', 'message:write'])]
    private ?string $text = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'project')]
    #[Groups(['message:read', 'message:write'])]
    private ?User $sender = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Notification::class, mappedBy: 'message', cascade: ['remove'])]
    #[Groups(['message:read', 'message:write'])]
    private Collection $notifications;
```

Notification.php:

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: NotificationRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(security: 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN") or object.user() == user'),
        new GetCollection(security: 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN") or object.user() == user'),
        new Post(),
        new Put(security: 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN") or object.user() == user'),
        new Patch(security: 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN") or object.user() == user'),
        new Delete(security: 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN") or object.user() == user')
    ],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['notification:read']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['notification:write']]
)]
class Notification
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['notification:read'])]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Message::class, inversedBy: 'notifications')]
    #[Groups(['notification:read', 'notification:write'])]
    private Collection $message;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(cascade: ['persist'], inversedBy: 'notifications')]
    #[Groups(['notification:read', 'notification:write'])]
    private ?User $userRead = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(['notification:read', 'notification:write'])]
    private ?bool $read_notification = null;
```

I´m also open for other design priciples